# Bot connects to chat but doesn't play audio - Discord.py Rewrite

Tags: python, ffmpeg, url-rewriting, discord

**Here is the command**
It passes no errors but still doesn't play any audio

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True,aliases=["Play,Song"])
async def playSongs(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    if not channel:
        await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel")
        return
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()
    source = FFmpegPCMAudio('song.m4a')
    player = voice.play(source)
```

Comment: I fixed it now, sorry!

Comment: please make a habit of saying how you fixed it.